# How should I make the markup of a responsive web-site when there is a lot of hidden content on mobile?

Tags: html, css, frontend, responsive

I'm about to begin a new project at work. I need advise: the problem is that I have to hide a few galleries, images and some other blocks of content on tablets and mobile phones. Are there ways to do it smarter than just to write display:none?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to avoid `display: none?`

Comment: SO is for code solution not for the advises

Comment: The purpose is not to load useless content! Optimization for mobile devices.

Comment: @BrianMacKay This question is not suitable for Software Engineering. We have very similar rules to questions being too broad as Stack Overflow. If this question were to be cross posted, it would be down voted, closed, and likely deleted very quickly and that is a poor user experience.

Comment: @ThomasOwens Understood! I think I must have missed some of the meta between SO, Programmers, and SE. I will be sure to read up.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using **Bootstrap**, you can add class `hidden-xs` to the elements to want to hide in mobile views.

```
<div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm"></div> <!-- will be shown only in md lg sizes -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use `height: 0;`, but I'm not sure if it's ethical.

EDIT: This page lists the alternatives for `display: none;`: [CSS Alternatives to style="display:none"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15855826/css-alternatives-to-style-displaynone)